3D Print Toolbox tab doesn't show up in Edit Mode
I installed add-on 3D Print Toolbox but can't see this tab in Edit Mode meanwhile in Object Mode it is.
How it can be fixed?



There seems to be a bug in the latest version. You should report it to the developer.
%AppData%\Blender Foundation\Blender\4.2\extensions\blender_org\print3d_toolbox\ui.py lines 16-23:
class Sidebar:
    bl_category = "3D Print"
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type = "UI"

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.mode in {"OBJECT", "EDIT"}

Poll function fails in edit mode since it's supposed to be "EDIT_MESH", not "EDIT". You can edit the file and save it and it should work(after restarting Blender or reloading the add-on by disabling and enabling it in the preferences). You can open the file easily by right-clicking on anything in the add-ons UI and choosing Edit Source(it should be added to Blender's Text Editor):

You have to have Developer Extras enabled in the preferences for that though:


It would probably be better to wait till the devs sort it out properly though. Not sure what modes it is intended to work with.

Thank you! This solve my problem.
Reported to developer.

You may have it filtered.

Installed add ons are not visible as separate tabs in sidebar
If your still having issues

Trying uninstalling the add-on
Restart Blender then install the add-on from
https://extensions.blender.org/
https://extensions.blender.org/add-ons/print3d-toolbox/

Also this might be helpful
3D print toolbox is missing from Add Ons

I tried installing from extensions platform and wasn't even sure it was supposed to work in edit mode, but it seems it should work since there is a clear bug in the poll function of the panel where it has "EDIT" instead of "EDIT_MESH" when checking if edit mode is active. It seems this one is definitely a bug. Not sure how to report it for an add-on though...

Should be 1 minute fix once it's reported though.

@MartynasŽiemys strange I'm using 4.2.3 on Ubuntu using 1.0.0 see animation above. I guess a new bug was introduced.

@MartynasŽiemys to report the bug they use this site for this plugin. https://projects.blender.org/extensions/print3d_toolbox/issues

Might it be that you migrated the add-ons installed previously?.. I just double checked, it seems to be broken with fresh install from extensions platform. Must be new.

@MartynasŽiemys could be I guess I won't be updating yet :-D

Oh, wow. It happened yesterday https://projects.blender.org/extensions/print3d_toolbox/commit/90bed690a3f6d081a5c11eb2239b677c01afd637

Confirmed! Version 1.1.1 was fine, but updating just now to 1.1.2 shows the bug.

Looks like they made the change.
https://projects.blender.org/extensions/print3d_toolbox/issues/11

Now updated to version 1.1.3 and working fine.
